# When using Ninject for dependeny injection is it best practices to use Ninject in your unit tests or use a mocking framework

Tags: unit-testing, ninject, justmock

I am using ninject to inject dependencies in my production environment. I see two options when it comes to writing unit tests. I can either create concrete classes and inject them using ninject, Or I can use a mocking framework like just mock.

My thought process is to just use both and have the deciding factor be whether or not the TestInterface can be constructed in a reusable way. This way we dont waste time writing the same Mocked method to return an empty list over and over again.

Is there a best practice for this type of thing?

Answer (score 3):

With unit tests on class, it doesn't make a lot of sense to include the DI container in the "system under test" (SUT).

- by principle, a class unit test should test the class and the class only
- usually you can't "reuse" the bindings in the unit test, you have to create them unit-test specific. Therefore you're only re-testing ninject, but not how you're applying it. Ninject is already tested. So no real benefit for you.

If you do acceptance testing / unit testing on component or application level, then it makes perfectly sense to include Ninject in the SUT.

For a class-level unit test one usually takes a dynamic proxy based mocking framework like [MOQ](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) or [FakeItEasy](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FakeItEasy).

given an implementation:

```
public interface IDependency {
    void Foo(string bar); 
}

public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly IDependency dependency;

    public SomeClass(IDependency dependency)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    } 

    public void SomeMethod(string arg)
    {
        this.dependency.Foo(arg);
    }
}
```

a test would look like (xUnit flavor):

```
public class SomeClassTest
{
    private readonly Mock<IDependency> dependency;

    private SomeClass testee;

    public SomeClassTest()
    {
        this.dependency = new Mock<IDependency>();

        this.testee = new SomeClass(this.dependency.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void SomeMethod_MustPassArgumentToFoo()
    {
        const string expectedArgument = "AnyArgument;

        this.testee.SomeMethod(expectedArgument);

        this.dependency.Verify(x => x.Foo(expectedArgument));
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't use Ninject in our unit tests as in the answer from BatteryBackupUnit (crazy name btw :-) ), but we use it in our Acceptance Tests. An acceptance test tests an (almost) complete feature (without UI, database or any other process-external API).

Comment: @Urs thanks for the explanation of acceptance tests. I've changed the text to mention "acceptance testing" instead of "spec testing" because it's more widely known and a more precisely defined term.

Answer (score 0):

JustMock has NInject built into it plus a [mocking container based on it](http://www.telerik.com/help/justmock/basic-usage-automocking.html).

Injecting mocks of dependencies is done automatically when you fetch the instance for the first time:

```
var container = new MockingContainer<ClassUnderTest>();
var testee = container.Instance;
```

Plus, you can use NInject's syntax for fine-grained control of the injection behavior, as well as JustMock's syntax for configuring mock behavior.